# Extract substrings/values from a long text

Tags: ruby

I have a long string/text, e.g.

`...blahblahblahblah,"shortcode":"Bk5z5Lgn1234",blahblahblablha...,"shortcode":"Wuipsz5Lgn1234",blahblahblablh...`

I'm looking to extract all substrings of the following pattern:

`"shortcode":"Bk5z5Lgn1234"`
`"shortcode":"Wuipsz5Lgn1234"`

The values of the shortcodes, i.e. `Bk5z5Lgn1234` and `Wuipsz5Lgn1234`, are of constant length (11 characters). Just getting the values will be fine. If getting all the occurrences of shortcode values is complicated, just getting the first value will be sufficient.

I know how to find the substrings (using the scan method), but I have no idea how to traverse the string and pull out the shortcode values.

Comment: Your question is not very clear. Can you post part of the text you're extracting from and the expected result of the function you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.
So, I have a string that looks similar to this:

"blahblahblahblahSOMETEXTHERE,"shortcode":"Bk5z5Lgn1234",blahblahblablhaSOMEMORETEXTHERE...,"shortcode":"Wuipsz5Lgn1234",blahblahblablhEVEN MORETEXT"

I would like to get the following (can be in an array): ["Bk5z5Lgn1234","Wuipsz5Lgn1234"]

Comment: It may help if you add the code that you have tried so far, to the question.

Comment: You're searching a string for certain substrings but there are no rules whatsoever, at least you didn't mention any. How are those 11 characters different from the rest of the text. There must be a pattern in the text by which those 'shortcode values' occur, that's why I asked for the real string(text) but you keep posting 'blahblahblahblahSOMETEXTHERE'.

Comment: This looks vaguely like JSON. Is it actually JSON? If so, parse it as JSON and do not use a regular expression.

Comment: OK. You've asked for the real example:
Open Chrome, type in: view-source:https://www.instagram.com/madona/

Now look for "shortcode":"BjRndHbH7M5"
What you have is (I believe) 10 of those on the page, they correspond to parts of URL of each instagram post.
I'm trying to get those 10 URLs. 

I still think my original post was clear enough...you have a lot of text with a few of these "shortcode" patterns that I've described. I'm trying to extract all shortcode values from this text that fit this pattern: "shortcode":"Bk5z5Lgn1234". I dunno...to me that's super clear.

Comment: *"It can be assumed that the values are of constant length (say 11 characters)."* This seems like a poor assumption given that the examples provided are 12 and 14 characters long respectively

Answer (score 2):

If the code is always in the exact format that you specified, and 11 characters long, this regular expression will find them:

```
"shortcode":"(.{11})"
```

The following will return all the matches:

```
text.scan(/"shortcode":"(.{11})"/)
```

This is admittedly likely not to be the most efficient solution, but simple and easy to use. Parsing HTML with regular expressions is never the best idea.

Comment: So simple. So brilliant. More than efficient enough. Thank you.